# Angularjs http.get method failed on some macs

Tags: mysql, angularjs, api, get, http-headers

I am using $http.get mthod to hit the mysql services to get the records of particulars table, even post and put is working fine. it fails on get method.

> In request header we have like this 
>   **Provisional headers shown**
>   Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization
>   Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
>   Host:d.example.com
>   Origin:http://localhost
>   Referer:http://localhost/xxxx/
>   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36

It shows "Provisional headers shown" error if this error happens it fails the api. can you give some suggestions where it goes wrong , actually i set all the headers in mysql services

> header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
>           header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
>           header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
>           header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
>           header("Accept: text/html,application/json,text/plain");
>           header("Content-Type: application/json");

Answer (score 0):

I found a solutions ....
Actually am using two services one for mysql and other for micro service mongoDB

So the problem is passing authentication header for mysql , now i remove the header for mysql service calls and the problem solved.

using below code

> $http.defaults.headers.common = {};

Which may help for others.